# Excel pivot to group by two columns and display sum of amount

Tags: excel, excel-formula

May sound weird, being a sql developer this groupby stuff is pretty easy but when it comes to excel, i have three columns say month-year, item, amount. Need to display the sum of amount grouped by month-year and item.

What ive tried is, to go selection of this table in worksheet and went pivot. Upon adding these two columns in row labels and adding amount column in values on pivottable field list i can get only zeros against the summed up column.

How to achieve displaying two columns as grouped by and sum of amount in the third column

From

```
month-year | item | Amount
Aug-2019   | Item1|    10
Aug-2019   | Item1|    10
Aug-2019   | Item1|    10
Aug-2019   | Item1|    10
Aug-2019   | Item2|     5
Aug-2019   | Item2|     5
```

To

```
month-year | item | Total
Aug-2019   | Item1|    40
Aug-2019   | Item2|    10
```

Do i require Pivot? or anyother else is achievable in excel like this?

Comment: With a Pivot table, just put both the two grouped columns in the Rows area, and `Show in Tabular Form` with `Repeat Item Labels`  You could also create this using `Power Query` aka `Get & Transform` in Excel 2010+

Comment: Or you could use SUMIFS() and some cells with data validation and control it that way.